# IF, OR and AND and the different results JavaScript

Tags: javascript, numbers, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I have to solve this problem:

> Write a function that adds two amounts with surcharge. For each amount less than or equal to 10, the surcharge is 1. For each amount greater than 10, the surcharge is 2. The call(5, 15) should return 23.

So I displayed this solution:

```
const addWithSurcharge = (a, b) => ((a <= 10) || (b <= 10) || Math.min(a + b, 20)) ? ((++a)) + ((++b)) : (2+a) + (2+b);
```

All goes smooth until the function takes (11, 10) as paramethers. If I use OR gives me 23, if I use AND gives me as a result 25, but not the desired 24. Am I doing something wrong? It seems that I am passing only the adding to one of the parameters. I am in my way of learning, so any help will be appreciate it.

Comment: The biggest problem is that your code is unreadable. Don't put that much logic into a single line of code. Spread it out and make it clearer.

Comment: I think the problem is you are not adding surcharge to each value individually.

Comment: Simplifying the code, making it more readable, will most likely also improve your chances of detecting the problem yourself. It will hopefully also make you understand why the condition will *never* be false.

Comment: Thanks to you guys. Well, glad I didn't post my first approach (one if, two else if and the last else) in the descrition. I will take the three comments and make the most of it. Last one though... I'll look deeper into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could treat every value and check the value and add the surcharge.

```
const 
    surcharge = v => v <= 10 ? 1 : 2,
    addWithSurcharge = (a, b) => a + surcharge(a) + b + surcharge(b);
```

Comment: Thanks a million. Does match the three comments above: splits the task, makes it clear what should happen in each case and adds the ammounts to every parameter.  I thought I was doing the same, but I see the differences between my "spaguetti" code and yours!

Answer (score 0):

And for if, else if and else. Works as a charm. Thanks [Nina Scholk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz)

```
const
   surchage = v => v <= 10 ? 1 : v <= 20 ? 2 : 3,
    addWithSurcharge = (a, b) => a + surchage1(a) + b + surchage1(b);
```